# adb shell command gives # eventhough the device is detected

Tags: adb, qualcomm

I am new to adb and when I run the adb shell

```
adb shell
```

command it gives the result lmi: /#. Even the

```
adb.exe shell
```

also gave the same result.
lmi is the name of my phone which is POCO F2 pro
[screen shot of the cmd page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko8Ya.jpg) Image is attached.
I am planning to enable Volte using the instruction in the following link
https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-volte-vowifi-xiaomi-phone.4573331/
I also checked this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IvNASKm_ypc
Unfortunately, I am stuck at the adb shell command or the adb.exe shell command which both gave me the result "lmi:/ #"
How can I proceed from here? I am using a USB cable (from the manufacturer) to connect the device to the laptop USB 2.0 port.

I tried different cables, enabling and disabling usb debugging but no avail. I am basically trying to follow the instruction in **https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-volte-vowifi-xiaomi-phone.4573331/** but was unable to move from the adb.exe shell command.

Please note that only one device is connected. I also used the adb -s e9861aaa shell command and it gave the same result.

Comment: looks liek shell prompt, isnt that expected ?? :)

Comment: So is that the expected output? I am new to this..

Comment: Idk, you tell me what did you expect